# Не могу передать свой класс через intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Из активити А я запускаю активити Б и хочу получить обратно через intent свой класс.
Редактор говорит, что ошибка в этой строке (активити Б):

```
intent.putExtra(Items.class.getSimpleName(), item);
```

Код, где я запускаю активити Б:

```
public void floatinButton1OnClick(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddElement.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}
```

Код из активити Б, где я кладу класс в интент и передаю его обратно в активити А:

```
public void floatingButton1OnClick(View view) {

    TextView tvTask = findViewById(R.id.task);
    TextView tvComment = findViewById(R.id.comment);

    String task = tvTask.getText().toString();
    String comment = tvComment.getText().toString();
    String firstDate = new String();
    String secondDate = new String();
    ArrayList<String> subtasks = new ArrayList<>();

    Items item = new Items(task, comment, firstDate, secondDate, subtasks);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(Items.class.getSimpleName(), item);

    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавьте `implements Serializable` для вашего класса

```
public class Items implements Serializable { ... }
```

Получение из интента:

```
Items items = (Items) intent.getSerializableExtra(Items.class.getSimpleName())
```

Comment: Спасибо, только чтобы получить надо использовать не `.getSerializable`, а `.getSerializableExtra`

Comment: @Харрис да, вы правы, исправил, `getSerializable` для `Bundle`